# Intersection of the kernel with the interpolation space

Tags: functional-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces, interpolation-theory

> Given two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ with a continuous inclusion $X\subset Y$, and another couple $X’ \subset Y’$ with the same properties. Take $f : Y \longrightarrow   Y’$ linear continuous, such that $f_{\mid X}$ induces a linear continuous map from $X$ to $X'$. My question is for $0<s<1$ and $p>1$, is the following true?
>
> $$(X\cap Ker(f),Ker(f))_{s,p}=Ker(f) \cap (X,Y)_{s,p}$$

Here I'm considering the K-method for the interpolation.

The inclusion $(X\cap Ker(f),Ker(f))_{s,p}\subset Ker(f) \cap (X,Y)_{s,p}$ follows directly from the definition. My problem is the other inclusion?

It's clear that if we have $Z\subset Y$ then in general the following is not true:

$(X\cap Z,Z)_{s,p}=Z \cap (X,Y)_{s,p}$,

someone can take $X=H^{2}(U)$, $Z=H^{1}(U)$, $Y=L^{2}(U)$, $s=\frac{1}{2}$, and $p=2$. But this does not contradict our case (cause $Z$ here is not even closed in $Y$).

If what I'm asking is not true, is it true under the following assumptions:

-$f(X)$ is closed in $X'$, and $f(Y)$ is closed in $Y'$, and

-$f$ is open onto $f(Y)$, and $f_{\mid X}$ is open onto $f(X)$.

Comment: The conditions under that formula holds are quite intricate. I refer to the lecture notes about [interpolation of subspaces](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313846656_Interpolation_of_subspaces) by Löfstrom, hopefully there is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you a lot! @rebo79